# How to handle google search ajax data using selenium

Tags: ajax, selenium, webdriver

How to handle google search ajax data using selenium (Type some string in google search, do not press enter key and check matching string data in search text box) ? How to get this data using selenium RC/Webdriver ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the action of some event (e.g. sendKeys, onClick, whatever) is going to trigger some event - like an Ajax request - you should be using waitFor until your condition is met (see the [Advanced Usage](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html) guide).

To avoid supplying a brittle timeout threshold on your test, you may want to call this in a Poll implementation, say once every 500ms 10 times for example, and then pass/fail accordingly

FitLibraryWeb has some nice, clean abstractions for this, but you'd need to use Fitnesse of course

Comment: thank u raven ..it worked i have used webdriver wait and waited for till ajax data loaded in my webpage.but one problem here is ajax ata is in following foramt Ex:apple string is searchign in google. <span>apple <b>store</b> <b>india</b></span>...this is the html source but i want to get complete data like apple,apple india,apple store ..how to get?any way?

Comment: WebElement<List> found = WebElement.find(By.xpath("//b")); iterate over each and call getText() is the short answer, but you really should read the getting started guide @ selenium.googlecode.com

Answer (score 0):

Thank u friends .. I am able to run a google search from selenium example code using firefox driver : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

Now i am trying to click on 'Change Location' available in left side pane after getting the search result but no luck. Code sample :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
element.submit();
WebElement expandLocation = driver.findElement(By.id("expand_location_link"));
expandLocation.click();
```

Debug info:
In view source i am not able to see the element expand_location_link but is visible in element inspect section of firefox/chrome or after saving the page from browser to local system.

Comment: Issue resolved by appending code : driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl());  before calling driver.findElement(By.id("expand_location_link"));